# 別のPCからdante socksサーバーに接続できない

Tags: linux

ご指導をお願いします。
CentOS7（さくらのVPS）上で [CentOSでSOCKSサーバ(Dante)を構築する](https://kagasu.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/26/173052) の手順通りにインストールしたら、localhost上で実行すると成功しますが、

```
curl --proxy socks5://160.16.x.x:1080 http://www.google.com -v
```

Windows10上のCMDで上記コマンドを実行すると、下記の警告が表示されました。

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
*   Trying 160.16.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 160.16.x.x port 1080 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to 160.16.x.x port 1080: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 160.16.x.x port 1080: Timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

うまくいったlocalhostでは、Proxy(160.16.x.x:1080)経由でwww.google.comにアクセスしています。
うまくいかなかったWindows10でも、このプロキシ経由でアクセスしようとしていて、`Time out`しています。
Windows10の環境に合ったプロキシを指定するか、プロキシを使っていないのであれば`--proxy`オプションを外す必要があります。

```
--proxy socks5://160.16.x.x:1080
```